# Is there any conventional notation for the point given by the intersection between two lines?

Tags: geometry, notation

I wonder if there is any conventional notation to denote the point given by the intersection between those two lines (assuming it exists)?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: If lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are considered as subsets of the plane (or any $\mathbb{R}^n$), then $\ell_1 \cap \ell_2$ is the set of all points they have in common. If they intersect in exactly one point, $\ell_1 \cap \ell_2$ is the singleton set containing that point.

Comment: @kccu That is a *solution* not a comment! (please add it below!)

Comment: @rschwieb I put it as a comment because (a) my answer gives the singleton set containing the intersection point, not the point itself, and (b) I'm not a geometer, so I may not be aware of "conventional notation" that is more common than what I suggested.

Comment: @kccu OK: although in this case I think, despite your uncertainty, you're already 100% on the mark.  In the set interpretation of incidence, the points *are* the singletons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

- A line *joins* two points
- A point *meets* two lines

With projective geometry and homogeneous coordinates, consider two points with coordinates

$$\begin{align} 
  {\bf P}_1 = & \pmatrix{x_1 \\ y_1 \\ 1} & {\bf P}_2 = & \pmatrix{x_2 \\ y_2 \\ 1}
\end{align}$$

<sub>NOTE: A scalar multiple of the above coordinates denote the same location. For example $\lambda \pmatrix{x & y & 1} = \pmatrix{\lambda x & \lambda y & \lambda}$ has still $(x,y)$ as the location of the points.</sub>

The line ${\bf L}$ that *joins* two two points has coefficients (line "coordinates")

$$ \begin{align} 
  {\bf L} =&  {\bf P}_1 \times {\bf P}_2 \\ 
  \pmatrix{a \\ b \\ c} & = \pmatrix{x_1\\y_1\\1} \times \pmatrix{x_2\\y_2\\1}
\end{align}$$

Where the equation of the line is $ax+by+c=0$, and $\times$ is the vector cross product

Now consider two lines with coefficients 
$$\begin{align} 
  {\bf L}_1 = & \pmatrix{a_1 \\ b_1 \\ c_1} & {\bf L}_2 = & \pmatrix{a_2 \\ b_2 \\ c_2}
\end{align}$$

The point where the two lines *meet* is has coordinates

$$ \begin{align} 
  {\bf P} =&  {\bf L}_1 \times {\bf L}_2 \\ 
  \pmatrix{x \lambda \\ y \lambda \\ \lambda} & = \pmatrix{a_1\\b_1\\c_1} \times \pmatrix{a_2\\b_2\\c_2}
\end{align}$$

### Example

A line $2x-y-1=0$ meets the line $x+2y-2=0$. Find the location of the point.

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \times \pmatrix{1 \\ 2 \\ -2} = \pmatrix{4 \\ 3 \\ 5}$$

The location is thus $\pmatrix{ \frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{5} }$

Comment: I am afraid that this is waaay off the mark, and I believe that the correct answer is given in @kccu's comments below the question.

Comment: OK, knowing how to find the point is useful, but if the contention is that $\times$ is standard notation for the intersection of two lines, I think that is not correct. It is the tool used to find the intersection, but I don't think it is used explicitly *for* the intersection in general.

Comment: The $\times$ is just the tool used. The notation is sometimes shown as $\otimes$ but it is not standard. The common notation is to use the words _join_ and _meet_ for these type of operations.